# Difference between Current and RC Kernels?

Tags: linux-kernel

What's the difference between

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.2-rc1-unstable/linux-headers-4.2.0-040200rc1_4.2.0-040200rc1.201507051635_all.deb
```

and

```
wget http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/daily/current/linux-headers-4.2.0-999_4.2.0-999.201507112205_all.deb
```

I would like to know not just if one is newer than the other, but also if they are both upgradable.

Comment: What do you mean upgradeable? One is a release candidate the other includes daily changes.

Comment: Braiam, first I want to thank you for taking the time to answer my question, by upgradable I mean that if rc2 would ever becomes rc3 through apt-get and so on till reach final release or it remains the same, I'm really bad posing questions, so please bear with my poor grammar and poor technical vocabulary, thanks again

Answer (score 1):

RC means Release Candidate. Is not the final version but very close to it, fixes are the only thing that can enter. Current is just the latest stable version, no changes should be made.